# Mockito retrofit2 with MVP architecture

Tags: kotlin, mockito, retrofit2, mvp

I think somethings wrong about my code in TeamImplsTest, and i need advice :D
This is my code

API interface

`interface API {
    @GET("lookupteam.php")
    fun getTeam(@Query("id") id: String): Call<TeamModel>
}`

TeamPresenter

`interface MatchPresenter {
    fun loadTeamDetail(team_id: String)
}`

TeamImpls

```
class TeamImpls(val teamView: TeamView) : TeamPresenter {

    override fun loadTeamDetail(team_id: String) {
        val call = RetrofitConfig().getApi().getTeam(team_id)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    val res = response.body()
                    res?.let { teamView.onSuccess(it) }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("PrevMatchFragment", t.toString())
            }
        })
    }
}
```

TeamModel

```
data class TeamModel(
        val teams: ArrayList
)

data class TeamModeLResult(
        val idTeam: String,
        val strTeam: String,
        val strAlternate: String,
        val strSport: String,
        val strStadium: String,
        val strTeamBadge: String
)
```

And

This my TeamImplsTest

```
class TeamImplsTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var teamView: TeamView

    @Mock
    private lateinit var teamPresenter: TeamPresenter

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        teamPresenter = TeamImpls(teamView)
    }

    @Test
    fun loadTeamDetail() {
        val teams = TeamModel(arrayListOf())

        val teamId = "133613"

        teamPresenter.loadTeamDetail(teamId)

        Mockito.verify(teamView).onSuccess(teams)
    }
}
```

i got error

```
Wanted but not invoked:
teamView.onSuccess(TeamModel(teams=[]));
-> at com.fathurradhy.matchschedule.domain.presenter.TeamImplsTest.loadTeamDetail(TeamImplsTest.kt:34)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
teamView.onSuccess(TeamModel(teams=[]));
-> at com.fathurradhy.matchschedule.domain.presenter.TeamImplsTest.loadTeamDetail(TeamImplsTest.kt:34)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about what exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: Can you please explain what is that is wrong? What are you experience? which errors, etc

Comment: I have changed my post..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not mocking the API call as loadTeamDetail creates its own API instance.

To enable you to test the API call behaviour you could provide the API instance through your constructor, e.g.

```
class TeamImpls(private val api: API, private val teamView: TeamView) : TeamPresenter {

    override fun loadTeamDetail(team_id: String) {
        val call = api.getTeam(team_id)
```

This would then allow you to mock the api behaviour and verify the presenter calls the correct method when the call fails/succeeds, e.g.

```
class TeamImplsTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var teamView: TeamView

    @Mock
    private lateinit var api: API

    @Mock
    private lateinit var teamPresenter: TeamPresenter

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        teamPresenter = TeamImpls(api, teamView)
    }

    @Test
    fun loadTeamDetail() {
        val teams = TeamModel(arrayListOf())

        val teamId = "133613"

        // Use retrofit-mock to create your mockResponse.
        // See: https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-mock
        Mockito.`when`(api.getTeam(teamId)).thenReturn(Calls.response(teams)

        teamPresenter.loadTeamDetail(teamId)

        Mockito.verify(teamView).onSuccess(teams)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry before, could u help me to check my github https://github.com/radhsyn83/match_schedule

Thanks